# mysql weird trigger errors

Tags: mysql, triggers

I'm trying to set up a trigger (run from a separate .sql file) to prevent insertion like this:

```
create trigger insert_formulas before insert on formulas    
for each row
    if ((new.formula_id_1 is not null) and (new.semantic_id_1 is not null)) 
    or ((new.formula_id_2 is not null) and (new.semantic_id_2 is not null))
    then
        signal sqlstate '45100';
        set @message_text = 'A formula cannot be a definition at the same time';
    end if;
```

It produces an error 1064 near '' at line 6 and near 'end if' at line 1. What have I done wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where's your trigger declaration? Please, provide full actual code

Comment: Ah yes, I've forgotten to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the [9.4. User-Defined Variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/user-variables.html) `@message_text` is different from `MESSAGE_TEXT` from the definition of [13.6.7.5. SIGNAL Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/signal.html)?

The following code creates the trigger correctly:

```sql
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER `insert_formulas` BEFORE INSERT ON `formulas`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF((NEW.`formula_id_1` IS NOT NULL AND NEW.`semantic_id_1` IS NOT NULL) OR
        (NEW.`formula_id_2` IS NOT NULL AND NEW.`semantic_id_2` IS NOT NULL)) THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45100'
        SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'A formula cannot be a definition at the same time';
    END IF;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Here [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/46073/1).